# Typescript changes type of Map value

Tags: typescript

I am newbie in TS and need some help. I've got really weird behavior of TS. I try to make a map of arrow functons and then call them by their name. Look at this

```
const first = (x: string): string => x.toUpperCase();
const second = (x: number): number => x ** 2

type FirstType = typeof first;
type SecondType = typeof second;

type MyUnion = FirstType | SecondType;

const handlers = new Map<string, MyUnion>();
handlers.set('first', first);
handlers.set('second', second);

// here myHandler has this type, as predicted:
// MyUnion | undefined
const myHandler = handlers.get('first');
if (myHandler) {
    // but here myHandler somehow has this type:
    // (x: never) => string | number

    // that's why i got this error
    // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
    const a = myHandler(10)
    
    // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
    const b = myHandler('asd')

}
```

Could enybody explain what's going on here? Why TS has changed type of the value of the map?

Comment: Since `myHandler` could potentially both be `(string) => string`, and `(number) => number`, to *safely* call it, the parameter must be string **and** number at the same time. That's *never* gonna happen, and hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your map returns a function whose only parameter is an intersection of all the possible types, and `number & string` have no overlap, hence the `never`.

The reason why it's invalid is because it assumes you will call the returned handler with a parameter whose type is valid for all of the registered handlers.

You could eventually do a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) to allow this:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-v41F9ncdUEV3xN8n4OmoQdD4cjCBjcfYCYgSZT4-TXyKHhsgMLufzhZQxfYpeA5ZAleQNeJdYbTegLeobbEo95XcYPb7ZK8IdqBHDtv3HMQAEYAAYZ2oHQtCAA)

```
interface StringHandler {
  type: 'string';
  handler: (x: string) => string;
}

interface NumberHandler {
  type: 'number';
  handler: (x: number) => number;
}

type HandlerUnion = StringHandler | NumberHandler

const handlers = new Map<string, HandlerUnion>();
const first: StringHandler = {
  type: 'string',
  // Notice x is already inferred as a string
  handler: x => x.toUpperCase(),
}
const second: NumberHandler = {
  type: 'number',
  // Notice x is already inferred as a string
  handler: x => x ** 2,
}

handlers.set('first', first);
handlers.set('second', second);

const myHandler = handlers.get('first');
if (myHandler) {
  // This check ensures the handler is a StringHandler thanks to the discriminant "type" property
  if (myHandler.type === 'string') {
    myHandler.handler('asd')
  }
  // This check ensures the handler is a NumberHandler thanks to the discriminant "type" property
  if (myHandler.type === 'number') {
    myHandler.handler(10)
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a union of functions, not an intersection.

Comment: I expressed myself badly, see my edit.

Comment: @nook Thank's a lot! Now I got it

Answer (score 0):

The map has nothing to do with it; the issue is with your `MyUnion` type:

```ts
declare const foo: MyUnion;
foo(0);
//  ^
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

When you union two TypeScript functions, the compiler doesn't know what the actual type of your parameters will be at runtime; without more information, it can only choose a type that satisfies all possibilities. In the case of your union, that type is `never` since `number` and `string` have no overlap.

Consider this example where the two function types do overlap:

```ts
interface Pet {
  name: string
}

interface Dog extends Pet {
  breed: string
}

declare function getBreed(d: Dog): string
declare function getPetType(p: Pet): string
declare const fn: typeof getPetType | typeof getBreed;
declare const p: Pet;
declare const d: Dog;

fn(d); // ok
// type hint:
//  const fn: (d: Dog) => string
fn(p);
// ^ 
//  Argument of type 'Pet' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dog'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoTMg3gKGckOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcxwF8cdRJZEUARAe1uQgAekEABMKaDNjzIARlAgQR5KjRD0mOERAQAbOPOQwAriARhg3EMloYAQvMUAKJch60AlMup1N2vQeNTc0trDHQwABUATwAHCEcY8nDPSm81X119FARLKkMQcjBYiG4YULBw6LjkAB9kIrjS8vsFEQBuDP9s3MxEiTAOrUyDHJA8lzcOnBgQZ3cOmYT5oA).

Here, `Dog` was the only type that satisfies both `Pet` and `Dog`.

This is related to the concept of [contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/6789816).